# What Dart library to use to implement a Pipe of Buffers?

Tags: dart

I want to find a way to reproduce the behavior of this Node library `buffer-pipe` ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer-pipe )

But I can't find a proper library in Dart. Any suggestions?

Comment: What should happen if you are requesting more data than the buffer contains? E.g. buffer contains 1 entry but you requests 5. Should we wait for more data or just return the data we have in the buffer? What if the buffer are empty?

Comment: @julemand101, more data than the buffer, it will return an empty array of bytes or the elements needed in it. 
cf. https://gitlab.com/mjbecze/buffer-pipe/-/blob/master/index.js#L20-25

I think I found out a package that is similar: https://github.com/isoos/buffer and I think it's what I need, this package throws some Exception.  I will play with it.

Comment: Ok, or else I don't think it is that complicated to make a similar API using a Queue/ListQueue behind the scene from the Dart SDK. I would have made an example using that but if you already have found an alternative then it is fine. :)

Comment: Always welcoming any answer to the question - 

It looks it uses a DoubleLinkedQueue<Uint8List> indeed https://github.com/isoos/buffer/blob/master/lib/buffer.dart#L308

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work. I have tried to mimic the buffer-pipe interface:

```
import 'dart:collection';

class BufferPipe<T> {
  int _bytesRead = 0;
  int _bytesWrote = 0;
  final DoubleLinkedQueue<T> _buffer = DoubleLinkedQueue<T>();

  List<T> read(int length) {
    final list = <T>[];

    for (var i = 0; i < length && _buffer.isNotEmpty; i++) {
      list.add(_buffer.removeFirst());
      _bytesRead++;
    }

    return list;
  }

  void write(Iterable<T> data) {
    final oldLength = _buffer.length;
    _buffer.addAll(data);
    _bytesWrote += _buffer.length - oldLength;
  }

  bool get end => _buffer.isEmpty;
  int get bytesRead => _bytesRead;
  int get bytesWrote => _bytesWrote;
}

void main() {
  final buffer = BufferPipe<int>();

  print('Read count: ${buffer.bytesRead} Write count: ${buffer.bytesWrote}');
  print('No more data? ${buffer.end}');
  buffer.write([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
  print('Read count: ${buffer.bytesRead} Write count: ${buffer.bytesWrote}');
  print('No more data? ${buffer.end}');
  print(buffer.read(6));
  print('Read count: ${buffer.bytesRead} Write count: ${buffer.bytesWrote}');
  print('No more data? ${buffer.end}');
  print(buffer.read(6));
  print('Read count: ${buffer.bytesRead} Write count: ${buffer.bytesWrote}');
  print('No more data? ${buffer.end}');
  print(buffer.read(6));
  print('Read count: ${buffer.bytesRead} Write count: ${buffer.bytesWrote}');
  print('No more data? ${buffer.end}');
}
```

Which returns:

```
Read count: 0 Write count: 0
No more data? true
Read count: 0 Write count: 9
No more data? false
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
Read count: 6 Write count: 9
No more data? false
[8, 9, 10]
Read count: 9 Write count: 9
No more data? true
[]
Read count: 9 Write count: 9
No more data? true
```

The class is made generic so it can be used for whatever type of data you want.

Comment: I want to add a comment about the weird counting in `write`. Since we takes a `Iterable` as input here, we don't know if the `length` operation of this `Iterable` is fast. In worst case, the `Iterable` will need to loop through each element to get the length. To prevent looping through data twice (count + add elements) I made my own logic here. Since `length` on `DoubleLinkedQueue` is fast (length is stored in a variable) I instead use that value to count number of elements added: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/9a588de9f4dad07e9ffce1012eef1c1470817da3/sdk/lib/collection/queue.dart#L264